# How to synchronise database with datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, data-synchronization, sqldataadapter

I want to syncronize my database with from my datagridview. When i modify, add or remove columns from my datagridview i want to update changed rows only.

Here is my code, but this code always insert new rows each time i run it so it has duplicate values.

```
        string conStr = "Server=servername,1433;Database=dbname;User ID=userid;Password=password;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
        public void UpdateDatabase(DataTable dtOldList, DataTable dtNewList)
        {
            string selectStatement = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sqlDa.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, conn);
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDa);
            dtOldList.Merge(dtNewList);
            DataTable d3 = dtNewList.GetChanges();
            sqlDa.Update(d3);
        }
```

Comment: How about using `sqlDa.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();` instead of merging & `GetChanges`?

Comment: I removed merge and get changes and used sqlDa.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();  but still inserts duplicate values. Also i removed sqlda.Update(d3); and this time i see no changes in database.